# Can't connect to wireless without typing sudo modprobe b43 in terminal

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I just upgraded to 12.04 on an old ACER Travelmate 5320 using Broadcom 4311. I wasn't able to connect to the internet through the wireless for a few days. It didn't even display wireless networks. I was finally able to make it work by following the instructions found here:
http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#supported

However, **each time I log on to the computer I have to go to the terminal and type
sudo modprobe b43
to make the wireless work. Is there somehow I can avoid this?**

I have used Ubuntu for many years but always relied on other people to help me with the technical stuff. The terminal is alien to me so I literally follow online forum instructions without knowing what I'm doing. Also, I tried many many things before I managed to make it work. So I'm worried I may have installed something that now conflicts with whatever the sudo modprobe b43 does.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Add `b43` in a line to the `/etc/modules` file. It will load the module at boot time.

Alternatively, You can add `b43` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and then use `sudo update-initramfs -u` to load the module automatically.